# UISearchController with UIBarPositionTopAttached throws UISearchBar offscreen; impossible to have standard UISearchController with UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to create a similar experience to the Contacts apps in iOS 8. The primary components of this are:

1. Keep the search bar fixed below the navigation bar
2. Have the search bar attach to the top of the view (standard functionality) when presenting.

This, however, is easier said than done. After a while of struggling with `tableHeaderView` (which didn't allow for interaction in front of the table view, and was complex with the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` positioning), I decided to embed a `UITableView` within a `UIViewController`, so I could add the `UISearchBar` as a subview. This worked pretty well, and allowed interaction with the search bar at all scroll positions, and the insets weren't hard to calculate.

**But, the search bar gets cut off below the status bar, when activated.** Seems like a straightforward issue—even if I didn't experience it with the *exact same implementation* in a `UITableViewController`. So, I tried making sure all my properties were set up for alignment, in every possible view controller.

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

I've tried every possible combination of these, in viewWillAppear as well as viewDidLoad, as well as translucent navigation bars and different starting frames for the table view and search bar. No luck. So, I tried to adjust the frames or constraints, perhaps using the topLayoutGuide or just 0. Unfortunately, adjusting the frame in any of the UISearchControllerDelegate methods didn't actually adjust its presented position, and adding constraints crashed immediately when the active animation begins (due to super.top not existing in the view hierarchy at the time; removing the constraints in willPresent did absolutely nothing).

After struggling for a bit longer, I tried implementing `positionForBar` as the `UISearchBar`'s delegate:

```
- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id <UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

**This seemed to adjust the height, but the search bar flies off the top of the view.** When activated, the search bar seems to appear directly *above* the visible area. This is even worse than it getting clipped behind or below the `UIStatusBar`. I also tried to just hide the status bar when the search controller becomes active, but conditionally implementing `prefersStatusBarHidden` didn't work at all (returning `YES` works great without `UISearchController` active, but when active it shows the status bar again or it gets shown beneath it). I assume this is because `UISearchController` refuses to obey any standards or rules, as is now painfully clear.

[image: debug hierarchy][image: inactive state][image: active state]

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now, and I can't think of a solution besides reimplementing the `UISearchController` class/animation entirely. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

For the behavior you described, this works great for me

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
```

And the following in your viewDidLoad function:

```
//Search Bar
        self.resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            self.definesPresentationContext = true
            return controller
        })()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, although this implementation would work great, it doesn't satisfy my requirements (#1 and #2 at the top of the question). I need the search bar to remain fixed even while scrolling.

Comment: @insanj have you tried setting the frame of the search bar as the y translation in view did scroll?

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense in this context. I'm already adding the search bar directly as a subview, _above_ the table view. If it were a `tableHeaderView`, that may make sense, but that solution is imperfect anyway (touches pass through). If you perhaps meant the y-translation of the search results table view, that would also seem too little too late: in the end, I'd need the frame adjustment to occur before any scrolling anyway (it dims before any search until a search is complete (standard `UISearchController`), and no didScroll happens there).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to subclass `UISearchController` and override the `prefersStatusBarHidden` in the subclass.

Also make sure View Controller Based Status Bar Appearance is set to `YES`

And in your viewcontroller containing the tableview / search bar:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I add a `UISearchController` to `UIViewController`,not using tableView.header. And the `UISearchBar.superview.frame.origin.y` is -44. So you cannot see the searchBar.

Method 1: You can change the frame of `UISearchBarWrapperView` in the `didPresentSearchController`,the delegate of `UISearchControllerDelegate`。But you will see the animation of this process.

Method 2: like JBlake say. Set `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;` after the `UISearchController` is `init`. It works!

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is if u need searchbar under navigationbar as u mentioned in #1 its very easy just set a boolean (Solution for #1) `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true`

Unfortunately i couldnt fix the searchbar-offscreen-issue while navigationbar is hidden.